# Serializing and deserializing a DateTime string doesn't work in UTC

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

Why does the following fail, and how can I fix it:

```
        DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        string foo = now.ToString("O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime bar = DateTime.ParseExact(foo, "O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Assert.AreEqual(now, bar);
```

Comment: can you explain what the `Assert.AreEqual();` method do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need return utc time

```
DateTime bar = DateTime.ParseExact(foo, "O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

more details please see [DateTimeStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind makes this work regardless of whether the input was DateTime.UtcNow or DateTime.Now.

Answer (score -1):

Please check if you can give Kind property while converting. I guess the second date is getting converted to local while the first one is UTC.

Comment: DateTimes are value types, not reference types.

Comment: Yes sorry I completely forgot that!